# Use of isKeyEntry(alias) in KeyStore - Java

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

I wanted to load the keystore file and get the details of its root SSL Certificate.

[Link to Sample](http://www.opencodez.com/java/read-x509-certificate-java-keystore.htm)

I saw the code in the above link. The code is also visible below. What is the use of `keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)`?

I check JavaDocs and it says

> Returns true if the entry identified by the given alias was created by a call to setKeyEntry, or created by a call to setEntry with a PrivateKeyEntry or a SecretKeyEntry.

**So, What is the use of it?**

```
        boolean isAliasWithPrivateKey = false;
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        // Provide location of Java Keystore and password for access
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(jksPath), jksPassword.toCharArray());

        // iterate over all aliases
        Enumeration<String> es = keyStore.aliases();
        String alias = "";
        while (es.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = (String) es.nextElement();
            // if alias refers to a private key break at that point
            // as we want to use that certificate
            if (isAliasWithPrivateKey = keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isAliasWithPrivateKey) {

            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias,
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(jksPassword.toCharArray()));

            PrivateKey myPrivateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();

            // Load certificate chain
            Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

            certDetails = new CertificateDetails();
            certDetails.setPrivateKey(myPrivateKey);
            certDetails.setX509Certificate((X509Certificate) chain[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Note `chain[0]` is the _leaf_ cert not the root cert

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 types of entries in a java keystore:

- *privateKeyEntry*, private key and associated certificate chain
- *trustedKeyEntry*, a trusted certificate (e.g. certificate from CA like Verisign, GoDaddy ...)
- *secretKeyEntry*, a encryption key (e.g. a symmetric key AES)

as described in the java docs, `KeyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)` returns `true` is you have secret or a private key.

The code example will fail if the entry is a secret key:

```
`KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(jksPassword.toCharArray()));`
```

it would be preferable to use:

```
`KeyStore.entryInstanceOf(alias , KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.class)`
```

Comment: In general yes, but JKS does not support secret keys so for it isKey == is private. PS: you have redundant markdown; use backticks OR indent-four not both.